# graphql error Sub selection required for type object of field Query

Tags: java, graphql

I am getting following error while invoking GraphQL Query in java application -

> "description": "Sub selection required for type Account of field
>   accountQuery",
>               "validationErrorType": "SubSelectionRequired",
>               "queryPath": [
>                   "accountQuery"
>               ],

Here is my schema -

> schema {   query: Query }
>
> type Query {   accountQuery(nbr: String): Account }
>
> type Account {   
> nbr: String 
>   name: String ... 
> }

I have Account POJO defined and i am calling a Service in the backend based on the nbr value passed which is working fine.
Here is the rest request i am sending -

> {   accountQuery(nbr: "123") }

Is the error due to missing id field and if so how do i mark "nbr" field as id ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In GraphQL, you always need to provide the fields you'd like to get in return from the query.

For example, if you'd like to get from the `Account` object the name and nbr fields, you need to specify it like that:

```
{ accountQuery(nbr: "123") {name, nbr}}
```

This is a key concept in GraphQL, whenever you query, you need to provide a `selection set`, that is- A set of fields requested in the query, you can never just return a full object, need to specify exactly which fields you'd like

Comment: This was the problem, Thanks.